# How can I find aircraft and airline listing data for planespotting?

Tags: plane-spotting

I vaguely remember when younger a spotter I knew having a book listing all airlines and all aircrafts within the airline at time of print. Is this data available now in book or online format? I'm looking to get back into spotting.

Comment: the book was most likely jp fleets which unfortunately has stopped being printed. They have an online version but it  requires a subscription which is pricey

Comment: https://www.flightaware.com/ might be a good choice also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find much of this sort of information at http://www.airfleets.net

For example, searching for [British Airways](http://www.airfleets.net/flottecie/British%20Airways.htm) lists their fleet, and clicking the number of active for a model (eg [A318](http://www.airfleets.net/flottecie/British%20Airways-active-a318.htm)) will list the tail number and other interesting information. From there you can click a [specific airplane](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-a318-4007.htm) for all the information along with a picture.

Answer (score 2):

[airfleets.net](http://www.airfleets.net) has details of aircraft with most airlines online and also in [paper and ebook](http://www.airfleets.net/shop/product.htm) formats.

Aircraft data is also available with [planespotters.net](https://www.planespotters.net/airlines) and also with [flightradar24.com](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/airplanes/).

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try [PlaneLogger](http://www.planelogger.com), which is an online site for logging your aircraft sightings. It has a large database similar to AirFleets, but allows you to mark off the aircraft as you seen them.